# How may I find out the Toplevel container of a widget?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5, introspection

I create, as usual, deeply nested frames of widgets which can sometime create other Toplevels. <del>frames.</del>

When I create a new Toplevel <del>frame</del>, I would like to store the originating Toplevel <del>frame</del> by which the new Toplevel has been created but since the button that has created it is deeply nested inside its own frame and has no knowledge of where it is in the hierarchy of its Toplevel, how might it discover its Toplevel container to pass it somewhere else?

Do I have to store it in advance in some sort of a global attribute or is there a way to find it out anyway by using some introspection?

Calling *any_widget._root()* gives me back the root container (the tkinter.Tk instance)... is there perhaps an amazingly undocumented *widget._toplevel* method?

**EDIT**: Deleted (for future reference) the word *frame* where its use was wrong and confusing.

Comment: `Toplevel` is a specific type of widget, and `Frame` is a specific type of widget. Thus, "Toplevel frame" is ambiguous. Are you asking about getting an instance of `Toplevel`, or an instance of `Frame`?

Comment: @Brian Oakley: You are right!, of course, ...though in my mind they have been often together because of how I had designed my classes in the past... I was asking about getting an instance of Toplevel, anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the widget method [winfo_toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_toplevel-method) which will return either an instance of `Toplevel` or `Tk`.

```
top = some_widget.winfo_toplevel()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think that by toplevel you meant the parent of the widget: if you created nested widgets like

```
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="text")
```

then `frame` is the parent of `label` and `root` is the parent of `frame`.

To access the parent of a widget, you can use the `winfo_parent` method to get the parent name, and then, the `nametowidget` method to get the actual widget corresponding to the name:

```
any_widget.nametowidget(any_widget.winfo_parent())
```

Comment: Actually I meant the Toplevel of all the widgets stuffed in a Frame whose master is the Toplevel.I understand what you mean, but that can be a problem when you don't know any more where you are and your widgets get stacked at different levels every time. Interesting the nametowidget method anyway.